# read image byte by byte doesn't work python

Tags: python

I have this function that writes image to a file byte by byte:

(The function stores in the first 2 bytes the amount of the rows in the image, the next 2 bytes it stores the amount of columns in the image and then in every byte the pixels rows by rows.)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.image import imread

def write_pic(pic_name):
    pic = imread(pic_name)
    height = pic.shape[0]
    width = pic.shape[1]

    with open("Resources/out.bin", "wb") as outfile:
        outfile.write(height.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big'))
        outfile.write(width.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big'))
        for x in pic:
            outfile.write(x.tobytes())
```

Then I have this function that reads an image byte by byte:

```
def read_pic(pic_name):
    with open(pic_name, "rb") as f:
        rows = int.from_bytes(f.read(2), byteorder='big')
        columns = int.from_bytes(f.read(2), byteorder='big')
        mat_pic = np.empty([rows, columns])
        print(rows)
        print(columns)
        while byte := f.read(1):
            for i in range(rows):
                for j in range(columns):
                    mat_pic[i][j] = int.from_bytes(byte, byteorder='big')
            if i == 287 and j == 511:
                break;

    cv2.imshow("The picture", mat_pic)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But when I show the image, it shows white picture, anyone knows why?
Also, I could not figure out why this while loop `while byte := f.read(1):` looped infinite times so I added this line

`if i == 287 and j == 511: break;`

I run this with these lines:

```
write_pic("Resources/pic.jpg")
read_pic("Resources/out.bin")
```

Comment: You read the file byte-by-byte, and for each of those bytes, you loop over the entire image and set each pixel to *that one byte*.

Comment: You don't need a loop at all.  `mat_pic = np.fromfile( f, dtype=np.uint8 ).reshape( rows, columns )`.

Comment: What's the point of this?  An uncompressed version of a JPEG is often 50 times larger than the compressed version, and contains no more information.  The compressed version already knows its width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's a JPEG, then you're probably getting an X by Y by 3 array, one for each color component.  You need to handle that.

Why do you write the height and width big-endian?  That's not natural any more.  Almost all systems you encounter today are little-endian.

This works:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.image import imread

def write_pic(pic_name):
    pic = cv2.imread(pic_name)
    print(pic.shape)
    height = pic.shape[0]
    width = pic.shape[1]

    with open("out.bin", "wb") as outfile:
        outfile.write(height.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big'))
        outfile.write(width.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big'))
        pic.tofile( outfile )

def read_pic(pic_name):
    with open(pic_name, "rb") as f:
        rows = int.from_bytes(f.read(2), byteorder='big')
        columns = int.from_bytes(f.read(2), byteorder='big')
        mat_pic = np.fromfile( f, dtype=np.uint8 ).reshape( (rows, columns, 3) )

    cv2.imshow("The picture", mat_pic)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

write_pic( 'walk.jpg' )
read_pic( 'out.bin' )
```